# Windows Phone 7.1 app accessing Azure Storage directly

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating a wp7.1 silverlight application and want to access azure blob and table storage directly. Searching all over the internet I can see using web application but I dont want to use web application for my silverlight application.

Is there a direct way to access azure storage directly from wp7.1 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WP7AzureQuickstarts](http://wp7azurequickstarts.codeplex.com/releases/view/65745) Library to start your project. This library has following 4 C# based project with full source code:

1. WP7AzureDirectory
2. WP7AzureLocator
3. WP7AzureNextGroupEvent
4. WP7FacebookAzure

If you download **WP7FacebookAzure** source code and look for **WindowsPhoneCloud.StorageClient library** which has full source code to access Azure Blob, Table and Queue storage directly from WP7 client application. You may need to understand security, SAS etc going forward.

Also you can download [Windows Azure Toolkit for WP7](http://watwp.codeplex.com/) source and modify the source code the way you would want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I asked one question after this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181105/error-adding-system-data-services-client-reference-to-windowsphone7-1-sdk