# Error adding System.Data.Services.Client reference to windowsphone7.1 sdk

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

After asking my first question [Windows Phone 7.1 app accessing Azure Storage directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171767/windows-phone-7-1-app-accessing-azure-storage-directly), I download  wp7facebookazure wp7.0 sample.

After i downloaded wp7facebookazure sample from http://wp7azurequickstarts.codeplex.com/releases/view/65745, I compiled WindowsPhoneCloud.StorageClient library, I see it is using custom System.Data.Services.Client library.

After I change the sample to use windowsphone7.1 sdk and then I add System.Data.Services.Client reference, I get following error:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.
```

How I can use windowsphone7.1 sdk System.Data.Services.Client  reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried in my machine:

1. Loaded WP7FacebookAzure solution
2. Upgraded solution to use Windows Phone SDK 7.1
3. Removed System.Data.Services.Client project completely
4. Added System.Data.Services.Client references from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Data Framework\Phone\v7.1\bin\System.Data.Services.Client.dll

There were some error which you work to remove however using above steps I was able to integrate System.Data.Services.Client.dll in WP7FacebookAzure solution.